# Are compile time and class loading time the same?

Tags: java

I am asking this question because in `Collection` I see that `Arrays.sort()` is overloaded, so I am wondering how someone can say that a static method is overloaded, when static methods are loaded at class loading time, and overloading is performed after class loading time.

My main question is: overloading and overriding are performed after class loading time; that's why they are visible to objects and invisible to static parts. So can static methods be overloaded?

Comment: Method overloading and class loading are unrelated concepts. Google and read about them separately.

Comment: why Arrays.sort() is overloaded , when it is static .

Answer (score 4):

*Compile time* and *class load time* are not the same thing.  And *run time* (in the sense that I use the term in the following ...) is something different again.

Overload analysis is performed at *compile time*, for both `static` and instance method calls.  The same is true for cases where one `static` method *shadows* another `static` method - it is resolved at *compile time*.

Override dispatching (for instance methods) occurs at *run time*; i.e. when the method call actually occurs, depending on the actual object that is the "target" object.

---

> why Arrays.sort() is overloaded , when it is static

Why shouldn't it be?

As I said, both `static` and instance methods can be overloaded.  (*Overriding* is restricted to instance methods, and instance methods only ... but overloading can be used with all kinds of methods, and to constructors too.)

Also "loading" and "overloading" are totally unrelated concepts.  "Loading" is about getting classes (in this case) into memory, but "overloading" is about different methods with different signatures that have the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Both static and dynamic polymorphism are part of polymorphism.

In static polymorphism, the overloading is resolved at compile time, in dynamic, it's resolved at runtime. In spite of that both are valid cases of overloading.